# Any news about SharePoint 15 release date?

Tags: features, 2013

As MS Office next version is scheduled to be released this year, I wonder is there any news about next version of SharePoint? I found a link for SharePoint 15 Technical Preview Interoperability API Documentation at
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28768

There is another site showing a screen shot on Metro API http://blog.fumus.de/sharepoint/2012/02/sharepoint-15-technical-preview/

Does anybody know when the next release is scheduled? Any reference where I can find more information?

Comment: I should point out that the screenshot you referenced is an artist's idea, not the real thing. It was a mock-up published sometime last fall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only 'fixed' information we know about dates at this point (early March) is that there will be a beta version of Office 15 and its companion software (SharePoint 15, Lync 15, etc) 'this summer'. We do not know anything beyond that, if 'knowing' is defined as what Microsoft has published. 'This summer' can technically mean anything up to and including August 31.

However, one TAP member leaked, in a LinkedIn comment, that the NDA for SharePoint 15 will be lifted in June. This coincides with several Microsoft conferences in the US and Europe scheduled for early and mid June.

Beyond that, As Benjamin mentioned, there's a major SharePoint event in November and it is very likely that Microsoft will want to be done by then.

.b

Answer (score 5):

I think any release date you see at present will be speculation as there is nothing official from Microsoft.

Many have speculated that MS will try to align the Office 15 release date with their conference in November, so I suppose the best answer anyone can give you right now is "probably the end of this year".

Comment: To expand on this, SharePoint is part and parcel of Office and they will be released at the same time. Any dates are pure speculation like Benjamin says.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2013 reached RTM on October 11, 2012.

Reference: [SP Team Blog](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=1035) & [Office Blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/office-news/archive/2012/10/11/office-reaches-rtm.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out SharePoint 2013 Preview at : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303422(v=office.15)